# Animation in a cell where as one text goes upwards out of the cell and another text comes upwards from bottom

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have to do a simple animation where in a cell. There are two labels in this cell. I want the text in it to move upwards out of the cell and at the same time next texts move upwards from bottom. I have done this using two separate labels apart from normal labels. These labels are in bottom of the cell which flow upwards from the bottom and then these four labels keep on moving in circular way. Is there anything better?

Instead of animating the labels Now I am animating View which contains two labels and an imageView to animate.Everything works fine except that imageView borders flicker a little bit.They don't move cleanly.Any reasons why UIImageView should can't move properly when its parent view's frame is moving in an animation.

Comment: This is how I would do it, is there some problem you're facing when doing it this way?

Comment: This is not solving my problem particularly, so I was thinking if there was a better way.